# Auth ::attempt is not working for login

Tags: laravel, authentication

My auth attempt when user login is not working as expected.It will always return else part when trying to attempt auth

```
public function tunneluserAuth(Request $request)
{



    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

 $password=Hash::make($request->input('password'));

 if (Auth::attempt(array('userLogin' => $request->input('email'), 
  'userPassword' => $password))) {

   echo "hi";exit;

 } 
else {

echo "here";exit;

 }

}
```

and my auth.php page is like,

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Entity\User::class,
    ],

     'companyUsers' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'companyUsers',
     ],
],
```

But it always returns else condition.why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use auth credential keys as email and password instead of userLogin and userPassword.

```
public function tunneluserAuth(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 
  'password' => $request->input('password')])) {

   echo "hi";exit;

 } 
else {

echo "here";exit;

 }

}
```

If you still want to use your own credential keys the use this -

```
$userData = User::where('userLogin',$request->input('email'))->first();
Auth::loginUsingId($userData->id);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}`
```

Source: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

this working here, try!

public function login(Request $request)
{

```
$email = $request->get('email');
$password = $request->get('password');

$user = new User();
$user_verify = $user->where('email', $email)
->where('password', $password)
->get()
->first();

if(isset($user_verify->name)){
    auth()->login($user_verify);
    session_start();
    $request->session()->put('name_user', $user_verify->name);
    $request->session()->put('id_user', $user_verify->id);



    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->with('message','Bem vindo '.$user_verify->name);


}else{
    return redirect()->route('login')->with('message','Usuario invalido');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).